# Django AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, django, datetime

i need some help with this python code, i am trying to generate some time data based on user input but i keep getting an error :

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I have tried several import statements like:
`from datetime import datetime, timedelta`
and also `import datetime` but the error persists. kindly help since i cant get my head around this.

```
def generate_time_slots(available_from, available_to):
    entry = []
    while available_from <= available_to:
        available_from = datetime(available_from).time() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10).time()

        entry.append(doctor_id = '1', date = '2018-07-11', avalable_slots= available_from,)
        for x in entry:
            Slots.objects.bulk_create(entry)
```

Comment: The number of questions of this type are the proof of how bad this lib was named...

Comment: Yes, i read those answers but i still did fully comprehend until nosklo gave his explanation below. Sorry if you are offended by my question. But sometimes you just need someone else to explain using different set of words.

Comment: I'm not offended by your question at all. But just remember there is a reason why @nosklo marked it as a **duplicate**. I understand that sometimes you understand better from certain peoples' explanations. But I will hardly believe you couldn't find any explanation on Stack about this specific problem since there is several threads on this error already (dupe included, answer are almost the same as accepted answer). Just Google it in the future, its good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `from datetime import datetime` which means your `datetime` name is already pointing to `datetime.datetime`. If you try to access `datetime.datetime` you will end up accessing `datetime.datetime.datetime` which doesn't exist.

You should use just `import datetime` instead, and in your code use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.timedelta`, but if you still want to use `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`, you have to change all `datetime.datetime`s in your code to say only `datetime` and `datetime.timedelta` to say only `timedelta`.

Comment: Thanks your explanation was far clearer than many of the other ones i have seen on stackoverflow and it helped to solve my problem.